# ajax return value in json format issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using some `jQuery` `post` request, as so

```
$.post('url', {data: some_data}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   console.log(data);  //to debug
   console.log(data.status == "ok");  //to debug
   ....
});
```

the `url` hits some `php` method which returns with

```
 echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
 exit;
```

the problem is that `console.log(data)` returns `{"status":"ok"}` but `console.log(data.status == "ok");` throws false. How can it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post() return only one object

```
$.post('url', {data: some_data}, function(data) {
   data = JSON.parse(data);//convert into JSON if data in string format
   console.log(data);  //to debug
   console.log(data.status == "ok");  //to debug
  ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should simple use Json decode:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

and then you can will be able to make comparison `data.status == "ok"`

Comment: I thought of this too but if this was the case, wouldn't the data object return "{"status":"ok"}" and not just {"status":"ok"} like the OP's scenario?